# Is there a way for properties of a class to inherit the validation of the parent class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, model

Say I have a class as follows

```
class Person {
    [Required]
    public string Firstname;

    [Required]
    public string Lastname;
}

class Record {
    [RequiredIfTrue("HasPerson")]
    public Person Person;

    [Required]
    public bool? HasPerson;
}
```

then I have some view code

```
<div showIfTrue("HasPerson")>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Person.Firstname);
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Person.Firstname);
    ...
</div>
```

My the fields should not fail to validate if `HasPerson` is false, but they do. Is there a way to write the models so this validates correctly?

i.e. Is there a way for properties of a class to inherit the validation of the parent class?

Comment: You would need a view model containing all 3 properties and then apply `[RequiredIfTrue("HasPerson")]` to `Firstname` and `Lastname`

Comment: @StephenMuecke in reality the `Person` class would have many properties and would be used in many different places, so combining the classes isn't practical.

Comment: Then it cant be done. But you editing data so you should be using a view model in any case.

Comment: @derekdreery You should have as many view models as you have views. Reusing view models can be problematic because different views will end up having different needs over time.

Comment: @FabioMilheiro In this scenario, the `Person` class isn't a view model - it represents a person in a hierarchical data store. The `Record` is the  ViewModel class

Comment: Alright, but then you should use a view model.